# Independent scrolling for 3 columns with individual column's header

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have created html for independent scrolling panel with individual column's fixed header & footer for 3 columns.

I have attached the wire-frame for your reference.

Q1: Is there any issue in my code?
Q2: will there be any issue during responsive design?

```css
html, body {
      height: 99%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      overflow: hidden;
      margin: 0px;
    }

    .container {
      max-height: 100%;
      overflow: auto;
      margin-top: 100px;
    }
    .col-1{
      float: left;
      width: 20%; 
      position: relative;
      height: calc(100vh - 140px);

    }
    .col-2{
      float: left;
      width: 20%;
      position: relative;
      height: calc(100vh - 140px)
    }
    .col-3{
      float: left;
      width: 60%;
      position: relative;
      height: calc(100vh - 140px)
    }
    .header, .footer,.header2, .footer2 ,.header3, .footer3 {
      height: 40px;
      
      position: fixed;
      margin-top: 60px;
      
    }
    .header {
      top: 0; 
      left: 20%;
      width:20%;
      background-color: #dddddd; 
    }
    .footer {
      bottom: 0;
      left: 20%;
      width:20%;
      background-color: #dddddd;
    }
    .header2 {
      top: 0;  
      left: 0%;
      width:20% ;
      background-color: #eeeeee;
    }
    .footer2 {
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      width:20% ;
      background-color: #eeeeee;
    }
    .header3 {
      top: 0;  
      left: 40%;
      width:60% ;
      background-color: #cccccc;
    }
    .footer3 {
      bottom: 0;
      left: 40%;
      width:60% ;
      background-color: #cccccc;
    }
    header{ position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 60px; background: #666666 }
    ul{ list-style: none; padding:0px; }
    ul li { list-style-type: none; display: block; padding:20px 10px; margin:0px; border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>
<header>Header</header>
  <div class="container col-1">
    <div class="header">
      Fixed Header
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="footer">
      Fixed footer
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container col-2">
    <div class="header2">
      Fixed Header
    </div>
    <div class="content">
     <ul>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
      <li>Listing</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="footer2">
      Fixed footer
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container col-3">
    <div class="header3">
      Fixed Header
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="footer3">
      Fixed footer
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you want these elements to stay fixed in these positions with a scrollbar?

Comment: and i want coffee . What have you tried to achieve this ? where is your code ?

Comment: Yes! i want these elements to stay fixed in these positions with a scrollbar & should be responsive later

Comment: i repeat. What have you tried to solve this ? where is your code ?

Comment: @divine I want this for mailbox...Please help me out. :-)

Comment: your question will be closed. noone will start making code for you for free

Comment: @Subh let me try

Comment: @divine Thank you!

Comment: @divine can you take a review of my code once if you have some time? I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: @Subh check my answer. Approach you have taken in implementing your requirement is fine. you could also try flexbox like i did (in my answer). and yes you need to analyze what kind of layout is preferred to show to the users on different screens

Comment: @MihaiT i regret helping this guy

Comment: @divine it's never a good idea to help someone who doesn't want to help themselves :)

Comment: Thankyou again @divine for supporting me :-)

Comment: @MihaiT I am believing in share knowledge to everyone and divine is not like you who is sick of earning money everytime. 

We all get enough money from our job and you should  remember onething that happiness is only feeling and it is comes from your inner soul. you can't buy happiness from money.

Comment: then accept the man's answer . That's the least you can do

Comment: @divine I am trying to accept your answer from yesterday. Please tell me how to accept answer?

Comment: @Subh i think Mihai T is the one doing the right thing here according to SO standards and i'm going overboard. Read the SO guidelines to understand what it is about and how to utilize its features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the question you posted is not the kind of question that is entertained by stackoverflow. It would be better if you adhere to SO standards. 
Take a look at my pen. i came up with this simple layout by looking at your wireframe image.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/Divine1/pen/qjmvXb)

Below is the skeleton of the layout

```
<div class="main_container">
<!-- main container -->
    <div class="header">
            header
    </div>
    <div class="content">
    <!-- content -->
        <div class="content_left">
        <!-- content_left -->
            <div class="cl_head">
                Fixed Header
            </div>
            <div class="cl_body">
            </div>
            <div class="cl_foot">
                Fixed Footer
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content_container">
            <div class="content_center">
            <!-- content_center -->
                <div class="cc_head">
                    Fixed Header
                </div>
                <div class="cc_body">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content_right">
            <!-- content_right -->
                <div class="cr_head">
                    Fixed Header
                </div>
                <div class="cr_body">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Devine.
 you have solved my question & I will keep it in my mind for future.

Comment: @Subh glad i could help. Accept my answer as it answers your question.

Comment: Left panel is not scrolling but it's OK, I will handle it from myself.

Comment: Hi divine i am sorry to say that i have less knowledge of flex...can you make scrollable left panel also?

Comment: @Subh i have updated my pen. you can check it. i have kept "fixed footer" for the left pane

Comment: Thank you! again 

I will love to do Photoshop work for you anytime if you need any help.

Comment: this is not working on Firefox. please tell me how to fix it on firefox?

Comment: @Subh of course, i didn't code for all browsers. i thought you will figure it out. incase if you haven't got the solution for firefox, Goto https://autoprefixer.github.io/ , copy the css from your code to this website and try using the generated css. i'm not 100% sure that will work. But you can try